# Custom TypeConverter with variable StandardValues

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid, typeconverter

I have a datagridview with info about competitors. I  display each copmetitor's properties in PropertyGrid. I want some of those properties (e.g. Degree, City, Institute) to be dropboxes with values taken from database. For this purpose i can create a custom TypeConvertor like this one

```
class DegreeTypeConverter : StringConverter
{
  static string[] _valueList = { "Bachelor", "Master", "Student" }; 

  public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(
     ITypeDescriptorContext context)
  {
     return true;
  }

  public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(
     ITypeDescriptorContext context)
  {
     return true;
  }


  public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(
     ITypeDescriptorContext context)
  {
     return new StandardValuesCollection(_valueList);
  }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(DegreeTypeConverter))]
  public string Degree
  {
     get { return _degree; }
     set { _degree = value; }
  }
```

But i want to get that valueList from database and i have 14 such properties so some universal converter would be much better than 14 converters with the only difference: valueList. Is it possible to create a TypeConverter with variable valueList (for example passed into TypeConverter as parameter in constructor)? Or maybe there's another way to have in PropertyGrid a dropbox with variable value list?
Hope it was clear enough
Thnx in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the GetStandardValues method, you are given a context. Use [context.Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedescriptorcontext.instance.aspx) to access the object that holds your property. Then interrogate it to get a service provider that will give you DB services. It could be through your own API or you could derive from [IServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iserviceprovider.aspx) and implement GetService, or why not get it through your IOC container as a singleton?